# Dynamic passed as parameter: return type cannot be inferred

Tags: c#

Recently, I came across an interesting issue with respect to using `dynamic` w.
When I pass a `dynamic` object as a parameter, the return type of that method is cannot be inferred.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

This code compiles successfully:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic data = new { SomeProperty = "ABC" };

        string response = IsTrue(data);
        if (response == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How can this compile?");
        }
    }

    private static bool IsTrue(object someData)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the above code, `IsTrue` returns a `bool` but the type of `response` is not inferred as `bool`. As a result, the above code compiles successfully.

On running the application, I get below runtime exception:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'
> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

How is this possible?

Comment: Interesting, I get a different exception: *An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call a method with an argument of type `dynamic`, the call is dynamically bound - so the compiler treats the return type as `dynamic` too.

There are some cases where the compiler *will* notice things that aren't feasible, but generally when you use `dynamic` you lose a lot of compile-time type safety. I'm slightly surprised by the exact exception you received (and it's not the exception I see) , but I'm not surprised that it compiled.

Note that this is *not* an interaction between `dynamic` and generics - the same code compiles with a non-generic method:

```cs
private static bool IsTrue(object someData)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the explanation. I'm using JetBrains rider, not sure if that is the reason for a different runtime error. I have also updated my question and removed the generics.

Comment: @Ankit: okay; it's generally not a great move to edit a question in a way that makes an answer make less sense afterwards. I'm not in a position to edit my post now; it'll have to wait until the morning, and until then it looks like I'm talking about generics for no reason at all.

Comment: Hi Jon, my apologies, I will be more careful next time.

Comment: I also ran the application through the command line using `dotnet run` and I got the same compilation error. Could be .NET Core vs .NET framework issue?